# What happens when I press buy button in software center?

Tags: installation, software-center

Just for my curiosity, what are processes happening,when I press buy button in software center ? . I just noticed that it updates software cache when I pressed buy button. It means it adds a temporary repository for that app?

Comment: I pretty much imagine that it should take you to a screen that will input credit card numbers and stuff to process for the transaction.

Comment: What if it is a free of cost app?

Comment: great question, I was wondering what happened in the background myself

Answer (score 3):

> After clicking on the Buy button, Ubuntu Software Center will prompt
>   you to login or create an Ubuntu Single Sign On account.
>
> Ubuntu Single Sign On (Ubuntu SSO) is a service provided by Canonical
>   Ltd that allows users to login to multiple websites and access
>   multiple services. Use your Ubuntu SSO to login to the following
>   Canonical websites:
>
> - Launchpad
> - Ubuntu One
> - Ubuntu Shop
>
> PURCHASING SOFTWARE
>
> If you already have an Ubuntu Single Sign On account, proceed with
>   your software purchase:
>
> 1. In the More Info screen, click on Buy
> 2. Login to your Ubuntu Single Sign On account
> 3. Review the Quantity, Description and Amount of your software
>      purchase
> 4. Enter your Billing address
> 5. Enter your Billing information
> 6. Click Review Payment to proceed (or cancel to stop)
> 7. Review your payment information
> 8. Click Submit Payment to purchase software<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:Ubuntu Software Center Documentation</sup>

If the App is free, but shows the buy button and $0.00 like the app in the image below, after you login, you will get

[image]

And below is the final outcome.  The App was installed without paying a dime.

[image]

For repositories, and how they integrate with USC see[Integration with Ubuntu Software Center.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks , but I need more technical data, ie, repository change, authentication , etc, and what happens , if the app is free of cost :)