# If I buy World of Goo in software center can I install it on my 2 ubuntu machines?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

Considering buying World of Goo from Ubuntu Software Center, but not sure [what happens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171959/what-happens-when-i-press-buy-button-in-software-center) after that.

All my computers use the same Ubuntu SSO account - does this mean I can install it on more than one machine for the one fee?

Comment: Yes, you can do it via single sso account, But it may be illegal as per the terms and conditions of that game

Comment: ...and you don't get to see those until you've commited to pay?

Comment: @Tachyons I recommend posting that, or something like it, as an answer. **artfulrobot**: That's a good point. Arguably paid apps should be required to show you the EULA before you buy them. I recommend [reporting that as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). I'd report it against the `software-center` package in Ubuntu. If it's not considered a real bug, it can be closed; if it belongs somewhere else, it can be retargeted to affect a different project/package.